# How to use Loadtest module to test load on my server on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For `Load testing` on my server, I am trying to use [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) but the thing is how can I use it with `Google App Engine` NodeJs `Flexible` application.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you posted the question **[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/KQD_kp3amog)** too. Here's the answer that was posted:

"[**Loadtest**](https://github.com/alexfernandez/loadtest) is a third-party library and is not supported by Google; therefore any issues/feature requests should be submitted to their **[Issue Tracker](https://github.com/alexfernandez/loadtest/issues)**.

That being said the tool simply runs locally on your development computer and sends a specific load of requests to your App Engine application at its **[appspot.com](http://appspot.com/)** or custom domain URL.

All further communications about this tool should occur in their **[issue tracker](https://github.com/alexfernandez/loadtest/issues)**."